# Ionic2: How to include signalr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, signalr, ionic2

Trying to utilize signalr in Ionic2.

Steps taken:

- Installed `signalr@2.2.1` and `jquery@2.2.3` with `npm`.
- Importing them with

  > ```
  >  import * as $ from 'node_modules/jquery';
  >  import 'node_modules/signalr';
  > ```
- Trying to establish connection with server with `$.hubConnection(..)`
- Fails on run, giving following error:

*jQuery was not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before the SignalR client JavaScript file.*

Answer (score 1):

I've found two options that have worked for me so far.

Option 1: You can add this block of code to the top of the jquery.signalR.js script file

`var $ = require('jquery');
window.jQuery = $;`

Option 2: You can download [signar-no-jquery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr-no-jquery) package. This package worked out of the box for me.

Goodluck

Comment: I had an issue with using jquery.signalR with angular cli 1.5. your solution did work. thanks.